# Should I upgrade AjaxControlKit dlls I downloaded in May 2010?

Tags: ajax, visual-studio

I am running vs2008 aspnet 3.5 and the ajax dll files I am using were downloaded in May 2010.

Is there a newer ajax release that I should be using for new development?

All my old stuff is working ok.

I am going to add that I am trying to get autocompleteextender to work and i cant get it wired up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to the ajax control toolkit project which is hosted on codeplex

- http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

If so then yes there's been a release since May 2010.  The most recent one is from November 2011 and can be downloaded here

- http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/76976

As to whether or not you should update ... that's a question best left for you to answer.  If everything is working fine and you don't find anything compelling in the new release then you're not obligated to update.  Though your release is almost 2 years old now, there's likely been changes since then you would benefit from.  It's at least worth your time to read up on the changes and see how they would apply to you.

Comment: I am trying to get autocompleteextender to work and i cant get it wired up. Could the version of ajax be the reason?

Comment: @TheMoot I'm not enough of an expert in the ajax toolkit to understand. I'd post that as a separate question as an there's likely someone on this site which can answer that.